# What's the equivalent of useRef in svelte?

Tags: d3.js, svelte

I have a component in svelte where I need to define a value inside it called `oldVal`, which is not bound to any `html` element, and initialize it to value X. The next time the component renders, I would like to update its value to X1, and this value should persist to the next render, and so. In react we use `useRef` for this, but how to implement this in svelte without having to write a store?

EDIT: adding some code

So, basically, I am doing transition inside the component, where I have a custom css transition function

```
<script>
export let tick;
export let tranX;
import {select} from 'd3-selection';
import {interpolate} from 'd3-interpolate';

// This value is initially 0 but then updated on each render
let oldVal =0;

//Custom CSS transition function
function animateX(node, {duration}){
const xTranslate = +select(node)
      .attr('transform')
      .split('(')[1]
      .split(',')[0];//Here I extract the translate value in the x direction
    const interVal =
      oldVal > xTranslate 
        ? interpolate(xTranslate , oldVal)
        : interpolate(oldVal, xTranslate );

    oldVal = xTranslate ; //Here I update the value, to interpolate values in the next render

    return {
      duration,
      css: (t) => {
        return `
        transform:translate(${interVal(t)},0);
        `;
      },
    };
  }
</script>

 <g
   opacity="1"
   transform="translate({tranX}, 0)"
   in:animateX={{ duration: 2000 }}
 >
   <line y2="6" stroke="black" />
   <text text-anchor="end" transform="rotate(-45)" y="20">{tick}</text>
 </g>
```

So, basically what I want to do, is in the first render to transition `g` from `0` to the computed value `xTranslate` and then update `oldValue` as `oldVal = xTranslate` so the next render `oldVal` starts with `xTranslate`

Comment: With ` next render` do you mean a new instance of this component ?

Comment: This is the x-axis of a d3 bar chart, where the labels depend on an array of data. The graph is interactive, and I can delete a bar from the bar chart, and the data and labels are updated accordingly. But when I delete a bar, I don't want to transition the remaining bars' labels from `0` to their new position, but rather from their last position to the new position. That's why I need to know their last position to make the transition.

Answer (score 6):

In Svelte, `useRef()` is `bind:this`.

```
<script>
  let inputEl;
  let handleClick = () => inputEl.focus()
</script>

<input bind:this={inputEl}/>
<button on:click={handleClick}>Focus</button>
```

You could find more React hooks examples in Svelte from this [repository](https://github.com/joshnuss/react-hooks-in-svelte)

Comment: In my code, the variable is not bound to an `html` element, though.

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: Create `oldVal` as a reactive store element?